# How can I use the Synapse library with Delphi XE3 and up?

Tags: delphi, tcp, delphi-xe3, ararat-synapse

Has anyone got a version of the [Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php) components and dproj package for delphi XE3+ ?
I'd like to have a go at using their component set but I can only find a Lazarus version.

Comment: Well, it's an open source project that lives here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/synalist/

Comment: Quote from [on-topic help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): `if your question generally covers software tools commonly used by programmers ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!`

Answer (score 2):

The project [change log on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/p/synalist/code/commit_browser) contains entries about BCB XE3 patches:

> r174 - compile fix for BCB XE3 (2013-02-05)

so I suggest to download / check out trunk and try to compile the library with XE3.

Packages are not required for basic Synapse classes, they can be created in code easily.

Comment: Is this only available as an lpk rather than a dpk?

Comment: We are talking about networking components. You can create them in code. Why do you need components? Surely it is not that hard to instantiate a component without having to use the mouse?

Comment: No that's fine, I just assumed there was a visual component set. I'll take another look at it.

Comment: Synapse website still states that Unicode delphi support is only at Beta level